# How to change the color of circles with the help of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

Hi so this is my project it didn't had any errors earlier but using the snippet tool an error is coming if you copy it and use it on software like visual studio code there will be no errors. my main problem is that I am trying to change the color of the circles by pressing the 'red' button but it doesn't seem to be working.

```js
let video;
let poseNet;
let leftEye, rightEye;
let nose;
let pose;
let colour_red;
let start;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.hide();
  video.size(width, height);
  poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelReady);
  poseNet.on("pose", gotPoses);
  colour_red = createButton("RED");
  colour_red.mousePressed(colourred);
  start = createButton("Start");
  start.mousePressed(start);
}


function gotPoses(poses) {
  if (poses.length > 0) {
    leftEye = poses[0].pose.leftEye;
    rightEye = poses[0].pose.rightEye;
    nose = poses[0].pose.nose;
  }
  pose = poses;
  console.log(pose);
}

function modelReady() {
  console.log("model loaded")
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  image(video, 0, 0);
  if (pose) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    circle(leftEye.x, leftEye.y, 50);
    circle(rightEye.x, rightEye.y, 50);
    circle(nose.x, nose.y, 50);
  }
}


function colourred() {
  fill(255, 200, 120);
  circle(leftEye.x, leftEye.y, 50);
  circle(rightEye.x, rightEye.y, 50);
  circle(nose.x, nose.y, 50);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
  </main>
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
let video;
let poseNet;
let leftEye, rightEye;
let nose;
let pose;
let colour_red;
let start;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
 video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.hide();
  video.size(width, height);
  poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelReady);
  poseNet.on("pose", gotPoses);
  colour_red = createButton("RED");
  colour_red.mousePressed(colourred);
  start = createButton("Start");
  start.mousePressed(start);
}


function gotPoses(poses){
  if (poses.length > 0){
    leftEye = poses[0].pose.leftEye;
    rightEye = poses[0].pose.rightEye;
    nose = poses[0].pose.nose;
  }
  pose = poses;
  console.log(pose);
}
function modelReady(){
  console.log("model loaded")
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  image(video,0,0);
  if(pose){
      fill(255,0,0);
    circle(leftEye.x,leftEye.y, 50);
    circle(rightEye.x,rightEye.y, 50);
    circle(nose.x, nose.y,50);
  }
}


function colourred(){
  fill(255,200,120);
  circle(leftEye.x,leftEye.y, 50);
    circle(rightEye.x,rightEye.y, 50);
    circle(nose.x, nose.y,50);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `draw()` function is continuously executing and you have `fill()` set to red. How would you expect it to change when you never change it? For the split second that `colourred()` executes it may change but the the eye you won't see it because it is immediately colored red again from the draw function. Try using a variable of some sort instead of hard coding it to red. I don;t use this library but here's something that works. There may be a better way to accomplish this also.

```
    let video;
    let poseNet;
    let leftEye, rightEye;
    let nose;
    let pose;
    let colour_red;
    let start;
    let color = [255, 0, 0]

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(640, 480);
      video = createCapture(VIDEO);
      video.hide();
      video.size(width, height);
      poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelReady);
      poseNet.on("pose", gotPoses);
      colour_red = createButton("RED");
      colour_red.mousePressed(colourred);
      start = createButton("Start");
      start.mousePressed(start);
    }


    function gotPoses(poses) {
      if (poses.length > 0) {
        leftEye = poses[0].pose.leftEye;
        rightEye = poses[0].pose.rightEye;
        nose = poses[0].pose.nose;
      }
      pose = poses;
      console.log(pose);
    }

    function modelReady() {
      console.log("model loaded")
    }

    function draw() {
      background(220);
      image(video, 0, 0);
      if (pose) {
        fill(...color)
        circle(leftEye.x, leftEye.y, 50);
        circle(rightEye.x, rightEye.y, 50);
        circle(nose.x, nose.y, 50);
      }
    }

    function colourred() {
      color = [random(255), random(255), random(255)]
    }
```